# Clarification about place for a question

Tags: discussion, code-golf, scope

I posted [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/what-is-a-good-way-to-deal-with-tasks-that-requires-arrays-using-haskell) question on [Programming Puzzles & Code-Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) and suddenly got a downvote and a comment, that my question is misplaced there. The downvote was removed after I wrote back, that the question is indeed on topic, but because I wasn't shure I opened [a meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/making-the-faq-more-precise). Many people told me there, that my question is suited better on SO, but since it is related to Code-Golf, I disagree to this. (Please also see quite similar on-topic questions during the commitment phase) Finally, they kept my question, but marked it as CW.

As the people on Codegolf told me, that the linked question rather belongs to Stack-Overflow, what is the opinion of the people at Stack-Overflow about this issue.

Comment: I don't see why questions about how to code golf aren't allowed on the site, or even need to be wikied, but it's not my site.

Comment: Use meta.codegolf to figure out what y'all want to be on topic there.  That discussion doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm inclined to agree with them; while there is a code-golf aspect to it, at root it's more a question about algorithms.  The meta-question is, what's the key aspect of the problem?  I would say it's less "how do I make this code smaller" than "how do I make this code *smarter*".

Comment: In my case, it was indeed *how to make this code smaller*